# Excel - Format cells in a row if less than date in another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Ok, I'm wanting my excel spreadsheet to format cells in a row if the date is less than another cell.

e.g.

Cells B40,C40, D40,etc turn red if less than A40

Cells B41,C41, D41 etc turn red if less than A41

I'd like to be able to drag the formatting into cells below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKNPE.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the home tab, go to "Conditional Formatting". Then click on New Rule. Then select the "use formula" option.

type approximately the following formula (in this case, your selection is B40):

```
=(B40<$A40)
```

and then apply a format to your choosing.

After finishing to apply the conditional format, you can copy-paste the format from B40 to the other cells (which will work, due to the $ sign before the A).

Comment: Brilliant! :)
I don't suppose you know of a way to prevent users 'dragging' the formatting and screwing it all up?

Comment: only if you protect the sheet, and lock the cells... (p.s. dont forget to mark it as answered).

Answer (score 1):

You can format your first row using conditional formatting.

Conditional formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Less Than

And then using small macro you can copy it to your selecting row/s.

```
Sub NewCF()
    Range("B1:D1").Copy
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        r.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Next r
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It does this by copying the format of the first row to EACH row in the selection (one by one, not altogether). Replace B1:D1 with the reference to the first row in your data table.